# List adjacent cell values if date belongs to month 1, 2, 3 (jan, feb, mar...) etc

Tags: excel

I have a list of dates in column `B` and a list of working hours in column `C`. I would like to get all the values (hours) listed in column `D` from column `C` if adjacent cell value in column `B` belongs to `Month 1 (January)`.

Then I would like to drag the formula downwards and to the right so that column `E` = `February`, column`F` = `March` etc.

The answer to column `D` should be a list with all the hours from column `C` that are in January in column`B` and by dragging the formula down and to the right to get the formula working for all the other Months as well.

Note that the dates might be in disorder!

I've tried with `INDEX MATCH` but I can't get my different formulas to work with the `MONTH()` function. I've tried to find an answer to the problem for many hours now without success. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your dates are being read correctly by first putting `=MONTH(A2)` and ensuring the appropriate value (1 - 12) comes out. Once you have verified that the following should do what you want.

In column D: `=IF(MONTH($C2)=1,$B2,"")` This formula can be dragged to the right first and replace 1 with 2 - 12 as appropriate for the month. Then copy them down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not solve the problem. The dates can be in lets say B2:B50 and the values I need in D2, E2, F2 etc. can be in any place between C2:C50. The code needs to check the first date from column B that is in January and copy the value from the respective cell in column C to column D, E, F etc. (without any empty cells in the "final list") depending on which month it belongs to. The first match of each month should be listed in cell D2, E2, F2 & the second match in D3, E3, F3 etc. without any empty cells until the last match has been found.

Comment: I found out how to get my formula to work. The formula is: =IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C;SMALL(IF($P$2:$P$50=(COLUMN(D$1)-3);ROW($B$2:$B$50));ROW()-ROW(D$2)+1));""). However, I would not like to use a helper column for this. At the moment I have calculated the month in a helper column P with the formula =IFERROR(MONTH(B2);"") and then used column P as one reference. I would like to use MONTH($B$2:$B$50=(COLUMN(D$1)-3) instead of $P$2:$P$50=(COLUMN(D$1)-3) but when I drag the formula to the right it gives me the same answer as for month 1 (January). All help appreciated again.